# How to identify a linear additive regression equation?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I am looking for some material/articles that tell the difference between linear additive and linear non-additive equations.

For example, based on my current understanding I can say that this [image: this] equation is both linear AND additive. Is my conclusion correct?

The equation is from [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3878161/).

Comment: "Additive" means you **don't** have interaction terms, so *no*.

Comment: @gung Really?  OP's model isn't additively separable in the original feature space, but it is "additive"